# Regex only match if character is not included directly before desired string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to solve [this CodingBat problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p136594):

> Return true if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts but "x.xyz" does not.
>
> xyzThere("abcxyz") → true
>   xyzThere("abc.xyz") → false
>   xyzThere("xyz.abc") → true

I'm trying to solve this with a regex, but I'm unsure how to handle `where the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period` requirement.

My solution for the problem without the constraint is this:

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
    return str.matches(".*xyz.*");
}
```

Any idea how to handle the said constraint with a regex?

Comment: [Negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) is what you are looking for. But to use it you also need to know about it [limits](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A negated character class should do the trick: `str.matches(".*(?:^|[^.])xyz.*")`

Here we're using a non capturing group `(?:^|[^.])` to ensure that we match either at the start of the string `^`, or at any position that isn't a period `[^.]`

Answer (score 8):

I personally used this solution, but there are quite a number of other variants:

```
str.matches("(.*[^.])?xyz.*")
```

I just make sure that if there is anything in front of `xyz`, then the period `.` does not immediately precede.

You can also write a look-behind solution:

```
str.matches(".*(?<!\\.)xyz.*");
```

`(?<!  )` part is negative lookbehind, and `\\.` (literal period) is the pattern that we want to check against.

Comment: @KelvinMackay: Java `matches` assume anchor.

Comment: I pass the test cases on CodingBat, though. Please provide test case that fails the code.

Comment: @KelvinMackay: The thing is the regex I wrote are equivalent to the version that has `^` in front and `$` at the back, courtesy of `matches` in `String` class. Your argument would be correct if the anchors were not assumed.

Comment: I understand that, but that's not why it doesn't work when I try it. Anyway, it's not important - it works on CodingBat so your answer's correct :)

Comment: I do believe that forces a compile every time using str.matches(arbitraryRegEx);

Comment: @Woot4Moo: You are right, but there is no way to prevent that from happening on CodingBat. Of course, it is better to compile with Pattern class before use in real code.

Comment: @nhahtdh Oh didnt realize coding bat limited the imports, good to know :)